# このほど、唯一残されていた、八王子隕石のかけらではないかとされる石について、本物かどうか、最新の科学技術で分析が試みられました

Tags: meaning, parsing

> このほど、唯一残されていた、八王子隕石のかけらではないかとされる石について、本物かどうか、最新の科学技術で分析が試みられました。([source](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/web_tokushu/2018_0202.html?utm_int=news_contents_news-closeup_002))

My attempt at translation:

> Lately, Concerning a stone treated as whether it is the only remaining fragment of hachioji meteorite, an analysis with latest technology was attempted.

I'm especially skeptical whether I parsed the attributes correctly or not, although the translation seems correct at least.

Comment: The English reads very unnaturally ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> このほど、
>   Recently,
>
> 〈唯一残されていた、｛（八王子隕石のかけらではないか）とされる石｝〉について、
>   (concerning/on) an only remaining stone which is considered (by some) as a candidate of a fragment of Hachioji meteorite,
>
> **本物かどうか、**（最新の科学技術で）分析が試みられました。
>   an analysis was carried out using the latest technology to determine whether or not it's a genuine one.

The analysis was to determine 本物かどうか (whether it's a genuine meteorite fragment), not 唯一残されていたかどうか (whether it's the last one). 唯一残されていた simply modifies the following 石.

- XをYとする: regard X as Y; consider X as Y
- XをYではないかとする: regard X as a candidate of Y; consider X might be Y
- YではないかとされるX: X which is regarded as a candidate of Y; X which is regarded as Y by some people