# How is と working here?

Tags: particles

海外で目指すビジネスのねらいについて、下村さんは、「僕らは『世界の農業の頭脳』になりたい。データを集めることで、例えば、*地球温暖化の原因**と**されるメタンガスをあまり出さない牛を*どうしたら作ることができるかも提案できる」と夢を語ってくれました。

Is と working here as WITH or IF or what?
Personally I think is WITH, but I am not so sure.

My breaking down of the sentence:
*地球温暖化の原因**と**されるメタンガスをあまり出さない牛をどうしたら作ることができるかも提案できる

earth warming's cause (WITH or IF or WHAT)done methane gas を not-much-emit cow を what things make が able may propose be able to.

Answer (score 2):

> 〔地球温暖化の原因**と**される〕メタンガス

As the other poster says, 地球温暖化の原因とされる is a relative clause that modifies メタンガス.

Now how about thinking of it this way...

Its non-relative version is: メタンガス**が**地球温暖化の原因**とされる**

「XXがYYとされる」 -- "XX is regarded as YY" "XX is considered to be YY".

So this literally means "Methane **is regarded as** the source of global warming".

And its non-passive version can be: （我々が）メタン**を**地球温暖化の原因**とする**

「（人が）XXをYYとする」 -- "(Someone) regard XX as YY".

which literally means "(We) **regard** methane **as** the source of global warming".

So the phrase in your sentence literally means:

> "Methane, which is regarded as the source of global warming"

For this grammar point, @Naruto's answer in this thread might help:

[Did I parse and interprete this sentence correctly?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56395/9831)

---

How about parsing the sentence this way:

> 〔〈（地球温暖化の原因とされる）メタンガスをあまり出さない〉牛をどうしたら作ることができるか*〕も提案できる

*Lit.* "We/I will be able to propose 〔how we/they can make cows 〈which don't emit much methane （which is considered as the source of global warming）〉〕.

<sub>*「どうしたら/どうすれば～～できるか」「どうしたら/どうすれば + potential」 means "How we can do~~" "What we should do to~~".</sub>

Answer (score 1):

This is a quotative use of と. 下村さん is explaining his aspiration for creating an overseas business.

The main sentence is

> 海外で目指すビジネスのねらいについて、下村さんは、夢を語ってくれました。

The nature of his dream is expressed in the と clause

> 僕らは『世界の農業の頭脳』になりたい。データを集めることで、例えば、地球温暖化の原因とされるメタンガスをあまり出さない牛をどうしたら作ることができるかも提案できる

Here’s a partial rendering

> Regarding his aspiration for an overseas business, Mr Shitamura told us about his dream of how they would like to become world experts in agriculture....

There is a second と in the phrase 原因とされる but in context, that's

> 地球温暖化の原因とされるメタンガス

which is a phrase where
.

> 地球温暖化の原因とされる

is a relative clause.  This clause says

> Methane, which is the source of global warming,...

Other than these two instances, there is no third instance of the particle と.
saying

Since from your comments it seems you wrestling with how these parts all fit together here is how to render the portion about their ambition:

> For example, from our collected data, we will be able to propose how we might create cows that don’t produce much methane which is a source of global warming.

Comment: But there is a と at the end in と夢を語ってくれました.   So two とs for quotation?

Comment: @davidpolygoth I've updated my answer.  I am, however, a bit confused by your comment.  Do you think there is a second と in と夢を語ってくれました?  There isn't.  The only place where I could see you thinking there might be is with 語{かた}ってくれた, but this is just how the verb 語{かた}る inflects.

Comment: Indeed there are only two と. I understand that the second one (と夢を語ってくれました。) is quotative, but it's the first one (地球温暖化の原因とされるメタンガス) which I cannot quite grasp its function in the sentence. When I break it down I cannot figure out how it is working. When I break it down after TATOEBA: earth warming's cause と(WITH or IF or WHAT)done methane gas を not-much-emit cow を what things make が able may propose be able to. That

Comment: @davidpolygoth updated answer further. i hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed it helped. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What about here: ロシアは北方領土を軍事的要衝と位置づけ、ミサイルや戦闘機の配備などを進めていて、軍備強化の実態が改めて鮮明になった形です。How is と working there? From what I have inferred I think it is working as AS. I have not been able to find information regarding my inference.

Comment: i wouldn’t look at it this way (that is, by focusing on the particle). i would focus on the verb and how particles are used with that verb. treating と literally in such contexts is probably not the best approach. by focusing more on the verbs and example sentences with those verbs, i believe, in the long run you’ll come to a more intuitive sense of what’s happening in the sentence.